# How to fix urlConnection.getResponseCode = 403

Tags: android, json, http-status-code-403, urlconnection, http-response-codes

Here is my code:

```
urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();    
                    int status = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
                    // Read the input stream into a String
                    InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                    if (inputStream == null) {
                        return;
                    }
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
```

Here is example of my JSON:

```
[{"Id":1,"Name":"Алупка","RegionId":1},{"Id":2,"Name":"Алушта","RegionId":1},{"Id":3,"Name":"Армянськ","RegionId":1}]
```

Here is URL: http://donor.ua/api/cities?sign=9u1AARsgKybup3vz9CaQnw==ivbCaKmrWpgz

But `urlConnection.getResponseCode()` still returns "403".

Please, tell me how to fix this!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried changing the URL to https? The server is telling me it is required, and when I change it, I get the payload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I try to load the URL you provided in the question, it says that HTTPS is required. Using Firebug, I confirmed that the server is in fact returning 403 in this case. Changing the protocol from `http` to `https` returns the JSON as expected. So, in your code, when you create your `URL` object, make sure that the URL you specified starts with https:// instead of http://

Answer (score 1):

The error could be due to server is rejecting the connection due to you are not sending "User-Agent".

add this line in order to fix it:

`connection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0");`